# django - adding userprofile to registration form. form not submitted

Tags: django, django-registration, user-profile

I have a registration form and am adding a user profile to add another field.

after the registration form is filled and submitted the form details are not submitted

models.py

```py
class UserProfile(models.Model):
  user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

  Assigned_Group = models.CharField(max_length=500)

  def __str__(self):
      return self.user.username
```

views.py

```py
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':

        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        profile_form = UserProfileForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()

            profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
            profile.user = user

            profile.save()

            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=raw_password)

            login(request, user)
            return redirect('index')
    else:
        form = RegistrationForm()
        profile_form = UserProfileForm()

    context = {'form': form, 'profile_form':profile_form}
    return render(request, 'registration/register.html', context )

def index(request):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
                username = request.user.username
        else:
                username = 'not logged in'
        context = {'username':username}
        return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

urls.py

```py
    path('Register/', views.register, name='register'),
```

Comment: this is my register.html page

```python

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
      
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Register</h2>
  <form action="{% url 'register' %}" method="POST">

    {% csrf_token %}
    
    {{ form.as_p }}
    {{ profile_form.as_p}}
    <input type="submit" value="Register">
  </form>
  
  </body>
</html>
{% endblock %}

Comment: the form is not submitted when i click register, could someone please check the view.py and let me know

Comment: please share your template code.

Answer (score 0):

in your html page in body you have to insert  {% csrf_token %} like:

```
    <html>
    <body>
    {% csrf_token %}
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your html form you will need to have inserted `{% csrf_token %}`.

See the [django docs on CSRF](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/csrf/) for more information or if you are using AJAX.

For example your html will then look something like.

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Side note from the django docs (which is important).

> In the corresponding view functions, ensure that RequestContext is used to render the response so that {% csrf_token %} will work properly. If you’re using the render() function, generic views, or contrib apps, you are covered already since these all use RequestContext.

Comment: i have included the {% csrf_token %} tag in the html already, but it does not work.

Comment: after i did some changes, the form is not submitted at all, please help